# Multiple has_many on same model, different fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Company` which belongs to model `Portfolio`. A portfolio can have multiple arrays of companies i.e. Sponsoring company list, Owning Companies list etc.

How can I use the `has_many` relations to include multiple instances of `Company` lists but call them by different names, as they are different fields but of the same type?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :portfolio_companies
  has_many :companies, :through => :portfolio_companies
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :portfolio_companies
 has_one :portfolio, :through => :portfolio_companies
end
```

```
class PortfolioCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :portfolio
 belongs_to :companies
end
```

With the help of above relationship you can use different kind of of type object Its may be has many or has one

You can define different field to associate it

Comment: What is `category_items ` ?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake its portfolio_companies a join table

Comment: I think this does not answer the question.  The author wants to add two relations to the `Portfolio` model: `sponsoring_companies`, `owning_companies`. In your example you have only one relation  `companies`.